# How to know the requested route

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm writing a custom `Route` class and are then using `return RedirectToRoute("MyRouteName")`.

How can I know that my own route was specially requested within the route class?

```
public bool IsRouteRequested()
{}
```

Would return `true` for `RedirecToRoute("MyRoute")` and `false` for `RedirectToAction("SomeAction", "SomeController")`.

Is it also possible to detect if `RedirectToAction` is invoked from within an area?

Comment: Where you will write the method "public bool IsRouteRequested()"?

Comment: Inside my Route derived class

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you serve, I do not like much but it is the only thing I can think of:

```
public static class RedirectToRouteResultExtensions
{
    private static IDictionary<RedirectToRouteResult, bool> typeRoute;

    public static RedirectToRouteResult SetRouteRequested(this RedirectToRouteResult redirectToRouteResult, bool value)
    {
        if (typeRoute == null)
        {
            typeRoute = new Dictionary<RedirectToRouteResult, bool>();
        }

        typeRoute[redirectToRouteResult] = value;

        return redirectToRouteResult;
    }

    public static bool IsRouteRequested(this RedirectToRouteResult redirectToRouteResult)
    {
        if (typeRoute == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return typeRoute.ContainsKey(redirectToRouteResult)
                    ? typeRoute[redirectToRouteResult]
                    : false;
    }
}
```

Example:

```
return RedirectToRoute("MyRouteName").SetRouteRequested(true);

return RedirectToAction("SomeAction", "SomeController");
```

*** Edit solution II ***

Prior to `return RedirectToRoute("MyRouteName")`, You can add information in the header of the response:

```
HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("CustomRoute", "1");
return RedirectToRoute("MyRouteName");
```

...

```
public bool IsRouteRequested()
{
   if (HttpContext.Response.Headers["CustomRoute"] != null &&
       HttpContext.Response.Headers["CustomRoute"] == "1")
       return true;  

   return false;

}
```

Comment: I was hoping for a solution that requires no external changes (other than inside the route class)

Answer (score 0):

You can just define a route value like this

```
return RedirectToRoute("myRoute", new { myVal = "val" });
```

and then check if it is available for ex in GetVirtualPath

```
public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
    {
         if(values["myVal"] != null)....
```

Comment: I know that. My question was for `RedirecToRoute("MyRoute")`. i.e. no other information than that the "MyRoute" as requested.

Comment: I don't think you can do that without passing any additional information. You can go either andres descalzo's answer or define your route url/constraint in such a way that it wont be matched the 'normal way' i.e. by regular request - this way you'll be sure that you've got there by being redirected.